# Add a non capturing group to a character class

Tags: regex

I am trying to define group of characters to be part of a charecter set to not match in my regular expression.

Sample input:

```
Karol-Ann
Karol-Ann Jeiger
Karol - Hann 
Karol | Hann 
Karol : Hann
```

Wished capture:

```
Karol-Ann
Karol-Ann Jeiger
Karol
Karol
Karol
```

My problem is that `/(?:\s+\-\s+)/` is successfully capturing blank characters with a dash in the middle, e.g. `-` but as sool as put them in a character class: `/[(?:\s+\-\s+)|:]/` they also match simple spaces.

Closest regex I have found so far `/^([^(?:\s+\-\s+)]*)/`

EDIT

Made it work with `/^(?:\s*((?:\w+(?:(?:-|\s+)\w)*)*))/`. The interesting element here is `/(?:-|\s+)/` allowing dash but without space around.

Pretty sure from the couple comments and answers here that, this the question is about something not possible with RE. Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: Maybe you want something like `^.*?(?=\s+[-:|]\s|$)`? You could also split with `\s+[-:|]\s` and get the first item

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
^\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/7hCZao/1